# The Electric Field and Magnetic Field of a Moving Charge

Tags: electromagnetism

When there is a charge moving at a constant speed $\vec{u}$, the induced electric field $\vec{E}$ and magnetic field $\vec{B}$ would be:

$$\beta=\frac{u}{c}\tag{01}$$

$$\vec{E}=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon r^2} \frac{1−\beta^2}{\left(1−\beta^2\sin^2\theta\right)^\frac32}\hat{r}\tag{02}$$

$$\vec{B}=\frac{\vec{u}\times\vec{E}}{c^2}\tag{03}$$

How to derive them?

Comment: Like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential#Derivation)?

Comment: @secavara: Looks like that, but it goes beyond what I can understand.

Comment: Alternatively, you can start with a frame in which the charge is static (where you know how to compute the fields) and then move with a constant relative velocity with respect to the charge. The fields in the moving frame can be computed using the transformation rules for boosts (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity#The_E_and_B_fields)). This approach is taken in a few references, the one I remember is Electrodynamics, by
Harald JW Muller-kirsten, in section 17.6, "Transformation from Rest Frame to Inertial Frame".

Comment: Thanks! I will try to understand the contents of the shared links.

Comment: Take a look in my answer here [Charges and relative motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/651969/charges-and-relative-motion/652210#652210) to "*...compute using the transformation rules for boosts...*" as in the comment by @secavara.

Comment: Also Related : **(1)** [Fields of a moving electron](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/352620/fields-of-a-moving-electron/382859#382859). **(2)** [Electric field associated with moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296904/electric-field-associated-with-moving-charge). **(3)** [Magnetic field due to a single moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412924/magnetic-field-due-to-a-single-moving-charge).

Comment: @Frobenius: Thanks for your answers!!